# Grouped barplot side by side

Tags: r

I'm trying to plot the table below using a grouped barplot with ggplot2.

How do I plot it in a way such that the scheduled audits and noofemails are plotted sided by side based on each day?

```
       Email Type Sent Month Sent Day Scheduled Audits Noofemails
27          A          1       30                7        581
29          A          1       31                0          9
1           A          2        1                2          8
26          B          1       29             1048      25312
28          B          1       30               23        170
30          B          1       31               18        109
2           B          2        1                6         93
3           B          2        2                9         86
4           B          2        4                3         21

ggplot(joined, aes(x=`Sent Day`, y=`Scheduled Audits`, fill = Noofemails )) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = position_dodge()) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1:29)) + 
  ggtitle("Number of emails sent in February") + 
  theme_classic()
```

[image]
Does not achieve the plot I hope to see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using this data format, so slightly new column names, no more back-ticks. `read_table(text = "")` is a nice way to share little datasets on Stack

```
joined <- read.table(text =
   "ID  Email_Type Sent_Month Sent_Day Scheduled_Audits Noofemails
    27          A          1       30                7        581
    29          A          1       31                0          9
    1           A          2        1                2          8
    26          B          1       29             1048      25312
    28          B          1       30               23        170
    30          B          1       31               18        109
    2           B          2        1                6         93
    3           B          2        2                9         86
    4           B          2        4                3         21",
    header = TRUE)
```

This is why ggplot2 really likes long data instead of wide data. Because it needs column names to create the aesthetics.

So you can use the function `tidyr::gather()` to rearrange the two columns  of interest into one with labels and one with values. This increase the number of rows in the data frame, so thats why its called long.

```
long <- tidyr::gather(joined,"key", "value", Scheduled_Audits, Noofemails)

ggplot(long, aes(Sent_Day, value, fill = key)) +
    geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use the melt() function from the reshape package. See example below.

```
library("ggplot2")
library(reshape2)

joined2 <- melt(joined[,c("Sent_Day", "Noofemails", "Scheduled_Audits")], id="Sent_Day")

ggplot(joined2, aes(x=`Sent_Day`, y= value, group = variable, fill= variable)) + 
geom_bar(stat="identity", position = position_dodge()) +
scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1:29)) + 
ggtitle("Number of emails sent in February") + 
theme_classic()
```